# Code execution flow, continue after function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Say I was to try and run code like this:

```
$('ul', bC).css({'width': $('ul', bC).width() + lW });
$(bC).find('ul li').eq(0).clone().appendTo('.boxScrollContainer ul');
scrollIt(bC);
$('ul', bC).css({'marginLeft': 0});
```

Would the jQuery CSS function after 'scrollIt' run?

I've been trying to figure out if it should, or I'm missing a fundamental of JavaScript

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it would run after scrollIt returns.

Comment: If the function returns, sure.

Comment: Why do you ask?  What is it that `scrollIt()` does that makes the answer not obvious?

Answer (score 0):

After as opposed to what other outcome? If you mean, is there a guaranteed order of execution? If so, yes.